# Does lemon burns the food in your stomach

Tags: weight-loss

So there is some saying, that drinking a cup of water, mixed with lemon in the morning, can help you lose weight, and some explain this, by saying that the lemon (which is acid) burns the leftover food in your stomach, so your body won't consume this food, thus not gaining more weight (even by a slity tiny percentage?).
I want to know how real these assumptions are.

Thank you.

Comment: No. Lemon does not do that to any real level. The acid in your stomach is hundreds of times stronger than what comes out of a lemon.